# HP ALM script to copy tests

Tags: workflow, alm, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

Here is my question: Is it possible to change the copy paste especially in test plan using workflow script ?

I need to make a script to copy and paste tests from one folder to another but the amount of information is too big to transfer (>= 25 000 item, it seems to be a bug and it was reported to HP but we got no answer). I'm trying to split the information and copy paste them by blocks with acceptable number of information to allow the copy.

I was trying to prevent the regular copy paste events from triggering and make my own but then i would like to call the action multiple times with less information but i can't figure how to call the actions or how to access the copied information. I didn't find either how to get the sourcefolder and destination folder paths.

Do you think it is possible to do it with the workflow script editor or do i have to add regular scripts to alm ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to your query is to use the REST API which is available on the QC back-end.

OF course this will require you to develop a bit of code. At least you will need to login properly to the QC by the usage of rest messages, find the folder you are looking for and then you can basically use in the header as `'Content-Type','application/atom+xml'` query, which will start to collect all the test cases in that folder (even if more then 25000).

I did the same in the past for other folders like requirements, where we had more than 100K occurrences.

Just as an hint --> the source and destination folder they will have a "unique ID" which you have to find out and use for the query.

To get the object in chunk, you have to use a page-size=%s&query={your_query}

A lot of queries regarding the below points are already answered in SO.

Hope this can help you a bit more!